# search from first table sum from second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form for search the user can enter any letter word and do his search
this search is in two tables
table 1 is `tbl_project`
this table contain

```
db_projectname db_location db_client  
xxxx              vvv      ccc

dddd              ggg      tttt
```

tbl_activities contain

```
db_projectname  db_cost  db_name   
xxxx             500     ttt
xxxx             500     hhh
dddd             200     llll
```

i use this php code to do my search

```
$sq = ""; 
$qq=array();
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){  
    $search =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['search']); 
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_projectname like '%".$search."%' ";  
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_location like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_client like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_offer like '%".$search."%' ";    
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_sheet like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_invoice like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_po like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_id like '%".$search."%' ";    
    } 
$second=true;
       foreach($qq as $que){  
        if($second){  
        $sq .= " where ".$que;      
        $second = false;  
        }else{  
        $sq .= " or ".$que;          
        }}
```

the result should be like this if the user enter x or v or c or xxxx or vvv or ccc

xxxx  1000  vvv   cccc

how should the query be to have this result i have bee tried different query but i didn't receive this result

```
SELECT  tbl_project.* 
      , (SELECT  sum(tbl_activities.db_totalcost) AS total_cost FROM tbl_activities {$sq}
FROM tbl_project
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
$cond = "";
if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){  
    $search =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['search']); 
    $cond .= " and pa.db_projectname like '%".$search."%' ";  
    $cond .= " and pa.db_location like '%".$search."%' ";
    $cond .= " and pa.db_client like '%".$search."%' ";
    $cond .= " and pa.db_offer like '%".$search."%' ";    
    $cond .= " and pa.db_sheet like '%".$search."%' ";
    $cond .= " and pa.db_invoice like '%".$search."%' ";
    $cond .= " and pa.db_po like '%".$search."%' ";
    $cond .= " and pa.db_id like '%".$search."%' ";    
}
```

And Query will be:

```
select p.*,sum(pa.db_totalcost) from tbl_project p left join 
tbl_activities pa on p.db_projectname=pa.db_projectname 
where 1 $cond group by p.db_projectname
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that:

```
SELECT p.db_projectname, IFNULL(a.total, 0) as total, p.db_location, p.db_client FROM tbl_project as p
LEFT JOIN (select db_projectname, sum(db_cost) as total from tbl_activities group by db_projectname) as a
    ON p.db_projectname = a.db_projectname
```

Comment: i receive this message Notice: Undefined index: total in C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\allproject.php on line 401   line 401 is:$total_cost=$res['total'];

Comment: @mohamadmohamad Sorry there was no alias for IFNULL. I've updated the answer.

Comment: sorry but it didn't work it didn't give me what i need no total and the search is not correct

Comment: i use this query it give the result i want but without the total SELECT
 tbl_project.db_id,tbl_project.db_projectname,tbl_project.db_location,sum(tbl_activities.db_totalcost) AS total_cost
FROM tbl_project LEFT JOIN tbl_activities ON tbl_project.db_projectname = tbl_activities.db_projectname {$sq}
GROUP BY tbl_project.db_id order by db_id desc

Comment: sorry with the total but not exact search problem with the name of project